# A question about conditional probability like a->c<-b, prove it/give a counter example

Tags: probability

There are three random variables, a, b and c. a is relevant to c, b is relevant to c, a is independent to b, So is a|c and b|c relevant? The conclusion is maybe yes, but I couldn't use solid mathematical methods to prove it. I know if c is a good function of a and b (like c=a+b), a|c and b|c is of course relevant. But now that a and b is only relevant to c, I have no idea about how to prove it, or maybe the proposition is wrong... Therefore, Can anybody prove it or give a counter example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.